# How to combine findMin() and delete() to remove smallest node in a BST?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a recRemove function that recursively removes the given node. I also have a findMin function that finds the smallest node in the BST. I'm having trouble merging the two so that I can remove the smallest(or largest) node. This is what I tried doing but it just returned garbage: Full code: https://pastebin.com/HCVsUZ4S

```
//remove min node in BST
node * extractMin() 
{
    return recRemove(root, findMin(root));
}
//delete node from tree
node * recRemove(node * root, double data)
{
    //3 cases: no children, one child, 2 children
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (data < root->data)
    {
        root->left = recRemove(root->left, data);
    }
    else if(data > root->data)
    {
        root->right = recRemove(root->right, data);
    }
    else
    {
        if (root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL) //no children
        {
            delete root;
            root = NULL;
            return root;
        }
        else if(root->left == NULL) //only right child
        {
            temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete temp;
            return root;
        }
        else if(root->right == NULL) //only left child
        {
            temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete temp;
            return root;
        }
        else //2 children
        {
            temp->data = findMin(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = recRemove(root->right, temp->data);
        }
    }

    return root;
}
//find min node in BST
double findMin(node * p)
{
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        //in a balanced BST the minimum node is the leftmost node so,
        //we traverse the left subtree until we get to the leftmost node and return and remove it.
        temp = p;
        while(temp->left != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        return temp->data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to debug your code? Learning to debug your own programs is an important part of learning to code. A debugger can allow you to step through your code and pinpoint where you have problems in your code. You can also debug your programs using things like print statements, and testing each part separately to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This isn't a free debugging service, and we expect you to show your efforts in debugging the program yourself. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: side note: I rather use heap for `findMin` which will be O(1)

Comment: `return recRemove(root, findMin(root));` -- There is nothing wrong with this call **if** `findMin` is not broken and `recRemove` is not broken.  In other words, you have bugs in either or both of those functions, and using `recRemove` in this manner exposes these bugs.

Answer (score 0):

sorry , can't write comments yet (will delete this later)

Where is temp defined? If it is a global variable than this is probably the issue...

**Edit:**
Have now seen the pasebin.....
temp is a member variable. Change it to a local variable.
Make sure to delete it before leaving the function. (best use std::unique_ptr<>)